# Top-down cops-and-robbers car game for MS-DOS

Tags: identify-this-game

Here are few things I remember, but it was not sufficient for me to find the game on a search engine:

- The game is top-down game - with no camera angle.
- It is a car game, with cops and robbers.
- You had to evade from the city when playing as the robbers without getting caught by the cops.
- When you reached a side of the map (a city town), you would won.
- There might be only on environment: a big city map (with no possible way to go outside).
- You could also play as the cops and I think I barely remember that it was harder to catch the robbers' car.
- It think it was a MS-DOS game  (80% sure).
- It think it was made in the 90's (95% sure).
- As I'm French myself, the game may have reached only the French market?

Comment: I'd be tempted to say one of the 2D Grand Theft Autos (GTA, GTA London 1961, GTA London 1969, GTA 2) but as far as I know while you could steal police cars, none of them let you actually *be* the cops.

Comment: Nope sorry, it's definitely not a GTA game - the purpose of the game was only to evade the city or to catch the robbers.

Comment: I also think you couldn't walk by foot, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: Was it single-screen or scrolling? Definitely MS-DOS and not Windows?

Comment: It might be single-screen because you had the opportunity to see the cops approaching and changing roads to escape them. Maybe the camera would be zooming-out while leaving the city... I bet it was a MS-DOS game but I'm not 100% sure also. The game looked definitely not as modern as the GTA ones you cited above. Sorry for lacking memory! :)

Comment: Sounds like it could be APB?

Comment: @David can you play as robbers in APB?

Comment: @StephenKitt - I remembered you could, but Wikipedia tells me you couldn't. I'd trust Wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry, it certainly was not APB. In my mind graphics were a bit more detailled than in APB - and also I think it was only a city playground. As I'm french myself, it is possible that the game was only edited in France - that would make the game harder for you to know it...I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Chicago 90 by Microids](https://www.mobygames.com/game/chicago-90)?

[image]

It has a 'gangsters mode' and a 'police mode', and the object is to escape the city, or to capture criminals before they escape. French developer, too.

Comment: Hell yes! Thank you so much. This is it! Wow I had completly forgotten the left part of the screen - but this is definitely this game.

Comment: Memory is a funny thing.

Comment: I was only 3yo when playing this game... Feels weird to think I was so young.